# Array Comparisons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I have 2 arrays as follows:
arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
Is it possible to ignore the position of array elements while comparing and give these both arrays as equal

Comment: well, they're not equal length, so .. no need to even test ... do you mean to check if all values in array2 appear in array1? no need to know positions either

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX

Comment: What makes these arrays equal?

Comment: array has methods called `every` and `inlcudes`

Comment: loop through arr 2 and check if value is inside arr1 with indexof for ex.